# How can I remove ridges from a concrete shower pan?

Tags: concrete, shower

I recently laid a new concrete shower pan, and went around the drain radially, which created some circular ridges.

I'd like to make the pan as smooth as possible, but these ridges are currently 1/8" to 1/4" high. How can I level these out, and do I even need to worry about it if I'm laying thinset when I put my tile down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need to concern yourself.  The thinset plus tile should smooth out the imperfections just fine.

If you really want to remove them, you'll probably need to use a concrete grinder.  But that's pretty expensive.  As a "lightweight" alternative, a 4" angle grinder with a  masonry wheel would knock the top off of the ridges.  But it would take a lot of time and make a lot of mess to really remove much material that way.